# Selenium (Java) - Creating a variable from xpath or a span?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium (with Java) and attempting to automate an entire process of creating a new  "raw material" item in our ERP. I have the raw material created, and when its done, at the top of the screen, it gives a new ID for that Raw Material. Normally at this point I would then pull up that Raw Material and edit it further on a separate page.

Looking at the code, it looks like this:

```
<span data-bind="text: rawMaterialCode" style="">RM001106</span>
```

The xpath looks like this:

```
/html//article[@id='bom-common-rawmaterialscreen-content']/div[1]/div[@class='tipsui5-container24']/div[@class='rowheight-oneline']/div[2]//span[.='RM001106']
```

I want to take that RM001106 (it will increment each time so any time I run this it will change) and append it to a URL..  So I want to run something like this:

First open a new tab, then
Variable rmat = "Code to get RM001106"
driver.navigate().to("https://myerp.com/RawMaterial/")+rmat;

So it will navigate to   https://myerp.com/RawMaterial/RM001106

Is this possible? How can I pull that value?

Comment: element.getText(), or element.getAttribute("innerHTML"); outta do it.